# Menu option with loop

Tags: java

I have a problem with addressing this part of my question. Even though it seems pretty easy I spent last few days debugging it. So, I have a menu that consists of 6 options. For example :

1. Buy pinsGood evening!
2. Buy quaffles
3. Do service Kit
4. Show Price list
5. Check out
6. (I am not sure whether I need to write it as a if else statement) execute the loop again if necessary.

In the beginning I tried to use a switch statement, but I couldnt use a value from one case and use it in another. So I tried to write this but the problem is that once I choose option 1 it will show me only option 1 regardless of what number I input after.

```
answermenuoption = inScan.nextInt();

while (answermenuoption != menustop) ;
{

    if (answermenuoption == 1) {
        prompt = "Please enter another item from the menu above: ";
        if (answermenuoption == 1) {

            System.out.println("How many pins do you want to buy?");

            pins = inScan.nextInt();

            if (pins > 10) {
                pricepins = pins * 18;
                System.out.println("Thank you.Your order received");

                System.out.println(menu);
            } else {
                pricepins = pins * 20;
                System.out.println("Thank you.Your order received");
                System.out.println(menu);
            }

        } else if (answermenuoption == 2) {
            System.out.println("How many quaffles do you want to buy?");
            quaffles = inScan.nextInt();

            if (quaffles > 5) {
                quafflesbox = quaffles / 5;
                quafflesindividual = quaffles % 5;
                pricequafflesbox = 580 * quafflesbox;
                pricequafflesindividual = quafflesindividual * 145;
                pricequaffles = quafflesbox * 580 + quafflesindividual * 145;

                System.out.println("Thank you.Your order received");
                System.out.println(menu);
            } else {
                pricequaffles = quafflesindividual * 145;
                System.out.println("Thank you.Your order received");
                System.out.println(menu);
            }

        } else if (answermenuoption == 3) {
            System.out.println("How many broomstick service kit do you want to buy?");
            broomsticks = inScan.nextInt();
            pricebroomsticks = broomsticks * 899;

            System.out.println("Thank you.Your order received");
            System.out.println(menu);
        } else if (answermenuoption == 4) {
            System.out.println(pricemenudiscount);
            System.out.println(menu);

        } else if (answermenuoption == 5) pricetotal = pricequaffles + pricebroomsticks + pricepins;

        if (pricetotal > 1493) {

            discountapplied = pricetotal * 0.1;
            pricetotal = pricetotal - discountapplied;

            System.out.println("The total price is:" + pricetotal);
            System.out.println("Price of pins:" + pricepins);
            System.out.println("Price of quaffles" + pricequaffles);
            System.out.println("Price for quaffles in the box of 5 = " + pricequafflesbox);
            System.out.println("Price for single quaffles = " + pricequafflesindividual);
            System.out.println("Price for broomstick service kits = " + pricebroomsticks);
            System.out.println("Discount applied: = " + discountapplied);

            System.out.println("Please input the money amount: ");
            moneyinput = inScan.nextInt();

            changetocustomer = moneyinput - pricetotal;
            System.out.println("Your change is:" + changetocustomer);
        } else {
            System.out.println("The total price is:" + pricetotal);
            System.out.println("Price of pins:" + pricepins);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can edit your question and add the code. also remove the comments afterwards

Comment: `while(...); {` - that `;` shouldn't be there.

Comment: And this perfectly demonstrates why the style of placing `{` at the end of line (rather than at the next line) is better.

Answer (score 0):

You only read `answermenuoption` at the beginning of the loop.

Try this:

```
int answermenuoption = inScan.nextInt();
        do
        {
            if(answermenuoption == 1)
            {
             //insert code
            }
            if(answermenuoption==2)
            {
            //insert code
            }

            //....

        }while((answermenuoption=inScan.nextInt())!=menustop);
```

Also note that this do-while will always run at least once. If you would like it to be able to exit on the first value just add the following code before the first if statement

```
if(answermenuoption == menustop)
    break;
```